# *= require font-awesome gives undefined method `dependency_paths' for #<Sprockets::StaticAsset:0x007fe40cf30208> error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, font-awesome

I am using rails 3.1.12, and wanted to use font-awesome-sass gem. So i included it in my gemfile, and did bundle install. Everything worked fine.

then I put `*= require font-awesome`  in application.css file, and started the server, but i get this error :

> **undefined method `dependency_paths' for "#< Sprockets::StaticAsset:0x007fe40cf30208>**

I think, its something to do with `*= require font-awesome`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use font-awesome version 3.1.1.0 or earlier.

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '3.1.1.0'
```

And then `bundle install`/`bundle update`

[Github Readme](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#changes)

And have you restarted the rails server?

Comment: But I'm using  gem 'font-awesome-sass' from [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass)
and that too version 4.0 with Rails 3.1.12